# How to build glibc with modified malloc which uses shm_open()?

Tags: makefile, build, shared-memory, glibc, librt

I am modifying the `malloc.c` and `hooks.c` file in `glibc` library and my modification uses `shm_open()`.

Now to build `glibc`, the [Man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) of `shm_open()` says that I need to **link with -lrt**.

The problem that I am facing is, as far as I know, `librt` is produced during the build process of `glibc`. How can I modify the makefile(s) to build `glibc` and also link `librt`?

Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have to recompile glibc at all.  Usually, this is not necessary for replacing `malloc`.  You can interposed glibc's `malloc` implementation from a DSO if you implement a certain set of functions:

- [Replacing `malloc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html)

This mechanism relies on ELF symbol interposition (perhaps via `LD_PRELOAD`).

Comment: I can't recompile all my applications to reflect the changes made in malloc modification. Can you suggest any other method?

Comment: You can use `LD_PRELOAD` to injection your own `malloc`.

Comment: The command to run the applications will change in this case as I need to load my library prior running the application and unfortunately I can't do that as well. Is there any way to achieve this without doing any changes in the compilation or execution of applications.